# TeachingDemos library in R

Tags: r, tk-toolkit

in the tkexamp method, how does one initialize a checkbox item to TRUE? what is the option I should use?
I have not found any examples so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking through the documentation? `?tkexamp` at the R prompt and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: what I need is something like this : `p=list('checkbox',value=TRUE)` but the value parameter does not exist or is not specified in the documentation. For example for 'combobox' you can say `type=list('combobox',init='b',
                   values=c('p','l','b','o','c','h','s','S','n'),
                        width=5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To default a checkbox to TRUE you need to set the init option to "T".

```
tkexamp( plot(1:10), list(ann=list('checkbox', init='T')) )
```

The next release of the package will have this documented better.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question (which is already answered) but shows an alternative for making simple interactive graphics in R. In this case, using the syntax of RStudio's `manipulate` package:

```
library(gWidgets) ## or use gWidgets2 from github
## get code
tmp <- tempfile()
cat(RCurl::getURL("https://raw.github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/master/inst/examples/manipulate.R"), file=tmp)
source(tmp)

# example like a tkexamp demo
# some common plotting parameters
x <- sort( runif(25,1,10) )
y <- rnorm(25, x)

w <- gwindow("Example of a simple to make graphic", visible=FALSE)
manipulate(plot(x, y, pch=pch, cex=cex/10, type=type, lwd=lwd, lty=lty),
           pch = slider(0, 25, 1, 1),
           cex = slider(1, 50, 15, 1),  # tcltk in steps of 1 not .1
           type = picker('p','l','b','o','c','h','s','S','n'),
           lwd = slider(0, 5, 1, 1),
           lty = slider(0, 6, 1, 1),
           ##
           container=w
           )
visible(w) <- TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm#M6):

> If a checkbutton is selected then the indicator is normally drawn with
>   a selected appearance, and a Tcl variable associated with the
>   checkbutton is set to a particular value (normally 1).

and vice versa